# jquery close and reset custom box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a simple Jquery question, I have a simple jquery popup form that displays a thank you message when users have completed it. They can then close it. I am having trouble getting the box to reset and show the original form once a user closes it.

```js
   //open popup Book a demo
 $(".actionButtonHeader, .bookADemoBTN").click(function(){
 $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
   $(".background_overlay").fadeIn(500);
 positionPopup();
 e.preventDefault();
 });
  


     var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

      var subscribed = document.getElementById("subscribed").value

      $("#overlay_form").submit(function(e)
   {
       var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
       $.ajax(
       {
           url : "demoEmailProcess.php",
           type: "POST",
           data : postData,
           success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
           {
     
         $(".formContent").html("<div id='messageDemo'><h2 style='text-align: center; font-size: 27px;'>Thank you "  + (fullName.value).split(" ")[0]+ "!" + "</h2>" + "<p style='font-size: 21px;'> Your message has beeen successfully sent. We appreciate your interest in Cybertonica and will get back to you within the next 24 hours. </p>" + "<a class='messageLink' href='index.php'>Return to Homepage</a></div>")
         
           },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
           {
                 
           }
       });
       e.preventDefault();
   });
    
   $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM


 //close popup Book a demo
 $(".close").click(function(){
 $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
 $(".background_overlay").fadeOut(500);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background_overlay"></div>
 <form id="overlay_form" style="display:none" action="" method="post" >
 <div class="close"><div class="innerClose">X</div></div>
 <div class="formContent">
  <b class="popupText">Want to see how we manage fraud and increase sales? We would love to hear from you. Book a demo with Cybertonica!</b>
  <p class="popupText">Briefly explain your business needs and how you manage fraud and we will happily get back to you within the next 24 hours.</p>
  <p id="returnmessage"></p>

  <div class="popupRowOne">

  <li><b>Full Name<sup>*</sup></b>
  <input id="fullName" name="fullName" required type="text">
  </li>

  <li><b>Company Name<sup>*</sup></b>
  <input required name="companyName" id="companyName" type="text"></li>
  </div>

  <div class="popupRowTwo">
  
  <li><b>Email<sup>*</sup></b>
  <input required name="address" id="address" type="text">
  </li>
  
  <li><b>Job Title<sup>*</sup></b>
  <input required name="jobTitle" id="jobTitle" type="text">
  </li>

  <li id="hiddenPot"><b>Please leave this blank<sup>*</sup></b>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </li>

  </div>

  <div class="popupRowThree">
   
   <li><b>Your Message<sup>*</sup></b>

   <input name="textMessage" id="textMessage" class="textareaPopup" required>
   
   </li>

  </div>
  
  <div id="contactSubscribe">

   <p class="checkBoxText"><input type="checkbox" id="subscribed" value="subscribed" name="subscribed" checked> I would like to sign up to Cybertonica newsletter</p>

   <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="popUpactionButton">Submit</button>

  </div>
 </div>
   
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After:

```
$(".background_overlay").fadeOut(500);
```

Add this line:

```
$("#overlay_form").reset();
```